# Como ordenar uma coluna no Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

É o seguinte, preciso ordernar uma pivot table para me mostrar os valores do maior para o menor.

```
impute_grps = df.pivot_table(values=["winPlacePerc"], 
                      index=["matchType"], 
                      aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
print(impute_grps)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só quero ordernar os valores desta saida.

Comment: Por favor, substitua a imagem por caracteres que possam ser copiados

Comment: se algum resposta resolveu seu problema, você poderia marcar uma das respostas como aceita. Entenda importância disso nesse link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O output do método `pivot_table` é um DataFrame, como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html). Desse modo, basta utilizar o método de `DataFrame` `sort_values`. No seu caso:

```
impute_grps.sort_values(by = "winPlacePerc", ascending = False)
```

Para mais detalhes, veja a documentação do método [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)